# Aligning images on two rows with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a flexbox with 6 boxes that go across the page.

However, for some reason it won't behave properly as they have different sizes.

[image]

they must behave like this:

[image]

```css
/* ================================= 
      Base Styles
    ==================================== */

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.row {
  flex: 1;
}
/* ================================= 
      Media Queries
    ==================================== */

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .main-header,
  .main-nav,
  .row {
    display: flex;
  }
  .main-header {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .col {
    flex: 1 50%;
  }
  .row {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .item-2 {
    order: -1;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .main-header {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .col {
    flex-basis: 0;
  }
  .item-1 {
    flex-grow: 1.4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="item-1 col">
    <img src="http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/img/portfolio/cabin.png">
  </div><!--/.primary-->

  <div class="item-2 col">
    <img src="http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/img/portfolio/cabin.png">
  </div><!--/.secondary-->

  <div class="item-3 col">
    <img src="http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/img/portfolio/cabin.png">
  </div><!--/.tertiary-->

  <div class="item-4 col">
    <img src="http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/img/portfolio/cabin.png">
  </div><!--/.tertiary-->

  <div class="item-5 col">
    <img src="http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/img/portfolio/cabin.png">
  </div><!--/.tertiary-->

  <div class="item-6 col">
    <img src="http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/img/portfolio/cabin.png">
  </div><!--/.tertiary-->

</div>
```

YOU CAN VIEW THE JSFIDDLE HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/ju157mnj/2/

Comment: What do you mean by "on a block level when it comes to small sizes of screens"? The pic you link indicates that you want the images to always stay in 2 rows of 3.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.col {
   flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 30px);   /* flex-basis adjustment for margin */
   margin: 5px;
}

img { 
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

    <div class="item-1 col">
        <img src="http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/img/portfolio/cabin.png">
    </div><!--/.primary-->

    <div class="item-2 col">
        <img src="http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/img/portfolio/cabin.png">
    </div><!--/.secondary-->

    <div class="item-3 col">
        <img src="http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/img/portfolio/cabin.png">
    </div><!--/.tertiary-->

    <div class="item-4 col">
        <img src="http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/img/portfolio/cabin.png">
    </div><!--/.tertiary-->

    <div class="item-5 col">
        <img src="http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/img/portfolio/cabin.png">
    </div><!--/.tertiary-->

    <div class="item-6 col">
        <img src="http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/img/portfolio/cabin.png">
    </div><!--/.tertiary-->

</div>
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ju157mnj/6/)

Comment: tried it here but for some reason the space between boxes are not good and they are not properly centered on the screen. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ju157mnj/5/

Comment: they are not also responsive. They must be on a block level when it comes to small sizes of screens: http://prntscr.com/b8ohf5

Comment: There's a lot of code in your example that doesn't relate, and possibly interferes, with your image layout. Please post a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, images in my demo now centered. Answer revised.

Answer (score 0):

Your images were quite massive and with your media queries it was a little difficult to edit. **However**, `flex` is powerful enough that you shouldn't need media queries. Below are two examples of how you could present your images (wasn't sure of how you wanted them).

Wraps:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.col img {
    height: 60px;
    width: 90px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/awvpezbt/

3 Per Row (no wrap):

```
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.col {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.col img {
    height: 60px;
    width: 90px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/awvpezbt/1/

Comment: tried it here but for some reason the space between boxes are not good and they are not properly centered on the screen. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ju157mnj/5/

Comment: they are not also responsive. They must be on a block level when it comes to small sizes of screens: http://prntscr.com/b8ohf5

Answer (score 0):

Made these changes to your css:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%; //Keeps the img in its container
}
.col {
  padding: 0 1em;
  flex: 1; 
  min-width: 200px;
}
.row {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v2tuoojd/

Comment: tried it here but for some reason the space between boxes are not good and they are not properly centered on the screen. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ju157mnj/5/

Comment: they are not also responsive. They must be on a block level when it comes to small sizes of screens: http://prntscr.com/b8ohf5